# How would I make a UIViewController appear to "slide out" from underneath another VC when using ViewController containment?

Tags: ipad, ios5, animation, uiviewcontroller

I am using ViewController containment, and I am targeting iOS5 and higher. I have a container viewController (A) that contains a sidebar (B), and a content area (C). I want it so when the user taps a button on the sidebar (B), a tableViewController (D)  will "slide out" from underneath the sidebar (B) and over the content area (C).

What would be the best way to approach this?

I am just beginning to wrap my head around basic viewController containment (a parent containing two viewControllers), but the sliding out of an additional viewController from underneath a child viewController has stumped.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take one of two approaches.

1. Use UIPopOverViewController on iPad.  This is pretty standard behavior for many iPad apps and Wanderlich has a great tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial) which I used on my first one.
2. You could also take the following steps:

   - Allocate, initialize, and style your table view.
   - Add it as a subview of its parent view controller.  Make sure its frame is underneath view controller B.
   - Use [viewcontrollerA bringSubviewToFront:viewcontrollerB];
   - Finally, use [UIView animateSubviews] to slide view controller D to where it should be.

When dismissing VCD, animate it out the same way you animated it in.

Hope that helps!